# How to assign the non-nullable local variable "_msg"

Tags: dart

I'm trying to make a Login form in flutter using a string function
here is the code:

```
String validateEmail(String value) {
  String _msg;
  RegExp regex = RegExp(
      r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$');
  if (value.isEmpty) {
     _msg = "Your username is required";
  } else if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
     _msg = "Please provide a valid email address";
  }
  return _msg;
}
```

I get this error:

> The non-nullable local variable '_msg' must be assigned before it can be used.

Comment: What string *do* you want to return if the email is good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you don't specify any `else` clause which means that in case of both your if's being false, the `_msg` will never get any value. That is a problem since the default value for any variable in Dart is `null` and the type `String` means we are not allow to set this variable to `null`.

So if no of the if-clauses are being executed, you would end up returning `null`.

Instead, this would be valid:

```dart
String validateEmail(String value) {
  String _msg;
  RegExp regex = RegExp(
      r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$');
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    _msg = "Your username is required";
  } else if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
    _msg = "Please provide a valid email address";
  } else {
    _msg = 'Some text';
    // throw Exception('Alternative, throw an error.');
  }
  return _msg;
}
```

(Yes, Dart is clever enough to recognise this pattern and will allow `String _msg;` in this case since it can safely ensure that `_msg` would always end up being given a value before we are using `_msg`.)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring your variables, make sure to instantiate them..

```
String _msg = "";
```

You can read more about flutter null safety here.

https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score -1):

You can change this line

```
String _msg;
```

to this

```
late String _msg;
```

Comment: Should be noted that this would just hide the error in this case. This might be fine if the developer know for sure that `_msg` would always get a value. But in this case, the analyzer might have a point since there are no else-clause and therefore a risk that `_msg` might unintended have not being given a value. The `late` solution would therefore move this problem to a runtime exception.